# Trouble getting acm graphics to display using eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, acm.graphics

I have been struggling to get acm graphics to display in eclipse. When I simply run the below code, the applet starts but nothing is displayed. The class is in default package in the source directory. Thanks in advance for any feedback.

```
import acm.graphics.*;
import acm.program.GraphicsProgram;
import java.awt.Color;

public class run extends GraphicsProgram{

public void oval() {
    GOval ov = new GOval(50,50,50,50);
    ov.setFilled(true);
    ov.setColor(java.awt.Color.green);
    add(ov);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `GraphicsProgram` `init` method which will be called automatically

```
public void init() {
   GOval ov = new GOval(50,50,50,50);
   ...
}
```

Comment: I think you are supposed to use `init` for GUI stuff, not `run`.

Comment: Just to clarify, for any "special" class, in this case one that extends graphics program, there is a particular method name that will be called automatically? Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, this is one of the predefined methods that is called by the framework, see the [javadoc](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~eroberts/jtf/javadoc/student/acm/program/GraphicsProgram.html#init()) for further details